# pached qt な wkhtmlpdf のインストール方法を教えて下さい

Tags: html, pdf

htmlをpdfに変換したく、wkhtmltopdfを使っています。
表示が想定より小さくなってしまい、解決策として `--disable-smart-shrinking` オプションを試そうと思っているのですが、以下のエラーが出て適用されません。

```
$ xvfb-run -- /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --disable-smart-shrinking $INPUT $OUTPUT
The switch --disable-smart-shrinking, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

そこで、patched qtなwkhtmltopdfをインストールしたいのですが、手順または参考になるドキュメント等あればご教授いただけないでしょうか？

以下のページなどを見ていたのですがgitorious.orgがなくなっていたりで躓いております。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981960/wkhtmltopdf-patched-qt

また、サイズが想定より小さくなってしまう問題に関して、他に考えられる原因があればご指摘頂けると幸いです。

環境は、ubuntu 14.04、wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: タイトルも日本語で書いていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルを日本語に修正しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macでしか確認できてないのですが、

`--disable-smart-shrinking` オプションを使いたいのであれば、

[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)
からダウンロードしてインストールすればよいように思います。

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

ドキュメントに

> wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)

や

> --disable-smart-shrinking       Disable the intelligent shrinking strategy
>                                         used by WebKit that makes the pixel/dpi
>                                         ratio none constant

と`--disable-smart-shrinking`オプションの記載があります。

Comment: apt-get経由では駄目だったのですが、ダウンロードしてインストールすると無事使えました。
ありがとうございます！